# Fixed element that goes off page but can be scrolled down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a page with a header, that header contains navigation and side 'navigation' that contains extra detail about the page.

Previously the header scrolled with the content, but to make the navigation easier to use it is now fixed. However, as the header is fixed the side navigation scrolls under the page title instead of staying in place (see gif).

Is there any way for the side navigation to stay fixed to the header but to not go off the end of the page? I've tried several ways, including placing it inside the navigation div itself. This prevents it from hiding behind the page header, but as the nav is fixed the page doesn't expand to show the full height of the side nav.

Current HTML structure:

```
<div id="page-title">
   This is the dark blue bit in the gif
</div>
<div id="nav">
   This is navigation
</div>
<div id="content">
   <div class="col-3" style="top: -30px;">
       This is where the page detail goes
   </div>
   <div class="col-9">
       This is where the content of the page goes
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I've put together a mock of what I mean on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khycg3ru/6/

Edit: As mentioned in the comments the "side navigation" varies in height, it could be say 500px high, or 2000px in which case it would be off the screen.

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/khycg3ru/5/)

Comment: I guess having the side navigation itself scroll could work, but is less than ideal as the side navigation varies in height depending on the page that you're on so I can't fix it's height.

Comment: it doesn't have a fixed height - it should be as tall as your page is and anything that overflows will scroll - if there isn't as much content then it won't have the scrollbar

Comment: Isn't saying it will be the height of the page fixing it's height? I guess I could have a div with no background so you can't tell it's there and put the 'side nav' within that.

Comment: Not really because the page can be any height - a fixed height would be a pixel amount but yes your workaround could be a div within the scrollable div - http://jsfiddle.net/khycg3ru/9/